# Encouraging users not to use multiple accounts for one question

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through the questions this morning, and on [this question here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/is-it-unprofessional-to-print-screen-a-presenters-notes-or-presentation) , the original poster (OP) seemed to have answered their own question from a **different account** This might lead to confusion for other readers. Is there a way for the community to discourage this behavior?

[image]

Comment: I think apart from voting the answer down and leaving a comment for the user, there's not much else.  The garbage collector will pick it up if it gets downvoted far enough.  In this case, the answer should have been a comment anyway.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be signup-related - as in, I offered an answer for something (on puzzling.se I think), and signed up at or around that point, but then didn't do the e-mail activation process in the same session (answered at work, signed up under private e-mail account, didn't do the verification until I got home). That meant that the answer I provided wasn't linked to my new account, so I couldn't comment on it, and I didn't have the rep to make comments generally. If that's the case with this question, this may have been the only way for the OP to respond.

Comment: Interestingly, a similar instance of this just cropped up: [Original Question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50377/career-path-for-developers) (Closed), [New Question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50693/from-developer-to-project-manager).

Answer (score 5):

On the specific case:

I suspect that the author of the question was confused by the user interface -- saw a textbox and, like on many discussion forums, typed into it to continue the conversation.  I suspect that she also was logged out (or using a different browser) and created a new account instead of signing back into the existing one.

I've left comments and deleted both answers, suggesting that she edit the information into the question.

In general:

The community helpfully flagged the non-answers, but the main question you're asking is about the duplicate accounts.  If you notice what seems to be a confused user with multiple accounts, go ahead and leave a comment along these lines:

> It looks like you might have created more than one account by accident.  If that's the case, please see [this help page about merging accounts](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Stack Exchange allows you to create more than one account *so long as the accounts don't interact* -- they don't vote for each other, they don't double-vote on something (voting on the same post from two accounts), accept each other's answers, or, broadly, to do anything on the site that a person couldn't do with only one account.  So just because someone's using two accounts, that doesn't automatically mean they need to be merged.  If you notice multiple-account shenanigans, though, then feel free to flag and explain what's going on.  If you do, please include the profile URL of the other account (not just the name).